# How to clone a git repository using access token in gitlab CICD securely?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have to setup a Gitlab CICD pipeline where I need to clone a repository. As I have 2FA setup, I'm using a group access token. Now I have set up this token in a secret variable in Gitlab and I'm using this in a url like
`git clone https://x:$gitlab_access_token@gitlab.com/x/x/x.git`

How can I clone this repository securely without passing the access token inside the url. Is there any way that I could do this securely?

I tried the above approach and its working but I am concerned with the security issue that it might cause. Also I dont want the access token to be stored in the runner.

Comment: Can you use ssh as transport instead of https? If so, you can setup an ssh key for the operation.

Comment: One solution is to cache the token in a credential helper.

Comment: Maybe [`CI_JOB_TOKEN`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html) can fit your use case?